How integrate AWS API Gateway (REST API) to Internal/private NLB and ALB then to Fargate
Someone knows how to configure this flow:
API Gateway (REST API) -> private NLB (Port 80) -> private ALB (Port 80) -> ECS Fargate (Port 8080)
My VPC only has 2 private subnets in different available zone.
When I try to deploy my task I get this error:
"Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered"
Someone has one example, resource or link that can help me.
I try to deploy a .net minimal api in ECS Fargate that can be consumed from API Gateway (REST API) through private NLB and private ALB.
The private ALB must route by using Path Pattern

It sounds like your ECS task is failing to deploy, which may not even be related to the load balancer, unless the health checks on the ALB are failing for some reason. You need to look at the ECS task stop reason, and possibly your ECS task's logs, to determine why the deployment is failing, and include those details in your question. As it is, there is not enough information here for anyone to help, and the information provided seems to be focusing on things other than the failed ECS deployment.
